# Angular 2/4 return an observable from within a then

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable, ionic3

I'm writing an http interceptor for an ionic 3 app. The interceptor gets a jwt out of local storage and adds it to the request header. The problem is that the method that gets the token returns a promise, which means that the interceptor can modify the request only after the promise is complete. But the interceptor needs to return a  Observable> (I'm new to angular 2/4 so I'm not sure if this is necessary.). Here's what I've got so far

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private storage: Storage) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var token = this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
        const dupReq = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('x-access-token', value) });
        return next.handle(dupReq);  // i need the intercept() function to return this  
    });
  }
}
```

After looking around for a bit I get the idea that I might be able to solve this using Observable.fromPromise() but I have no  idea how to do it

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer, I don't want post a bad answer but maybe you can test this:  return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token')).map(token => {const dupReq = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('x-access-token', token) }); return next.handle(dupReq); }); If it's ok, I post the code

Comment: @mickaelw That's exactly what I'm trying. Not sure if it'll work, I'll post an edit if it does. Post a answer once you get access to your computer